# How to create a form for a reference_many association with existing references? (mongoid 2.0.0.beta.20)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Assume I've a model A which is referencing many other models B. I have a set of B's and want to create a form which creates/destroys the association (many-to-many).

What's is the best approach to do that? Can I somehow use `accept_nested_attribures_for` and the `fields_for` helper like I'd use to create new reference objects?

**Edit: Example**

I have a model *Category* and another model *Post*. I want each *Post* to **reference_many** *Categories*. I have a static set categories. So I don't want to create new categories but create references to the existing categories.

What is the easiest way to extend the new/edit form of *Post* with a category selection. Right now I'm processing the categories manually because I couldn't figure out how to use `accept_nested_attribures_for` and `fields_for` with existing reference objects.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you clarify using real example? BTW you can use `accept_nested_attribures_for` with mongoid and `fields_for` helper as well.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my post. I know that I can use `accept_nested_attribures_for` and `fields_for` with mongoid. But don't know if and how to use those helpers in my specific case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `references_and_referenced_in_many` for describing associations between Posts and Categories but it exists in mongoid since 2.0.0.rc.1. You can explicitly define model for many-to-many associations, in your case, for ex., `PostCategory`:

```
class PostCategory
  include Mongoid::Document
  referenced_in :category, :inverse_of => :post_categories
  referenced_in :post, :inverse_of => :post_categories
end

class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  references_many :post_categories
end

class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  references_many :post_categories, :dependent => :delete

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_categories
  attr_accessible :post_categories_attributes  
end
```

In the view (I use [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and haml here, but the same approach with old dirty form_for and ERB):

```
= simple_form_for setup_post(@post) do |f|
  ...
  = f.simple_field_for :post_categories do |n|
    = n.input :category, :as => :select, :collection => Category.asc(:name).all
```

The last (but not least) thing is `setup_post` helper which did the trick:

```
module PostsHelper
  def setup_post(post)
    post.tap do |p|
      p.post_categories.build if p.post_categories.empty?
    end
  end
end
```

That's all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I like the approach. Looks like I really have to update to the rc versions (finally) :-)

Comment: I've updated mongoid to rc7. What would change in the above example if I'd use references_and_referenced_in_many?